# creating xml on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xml

ı wanna create xml file on aspx.cs but ı have no idea what ı need to do.can anyone help me?
ı don't want to use database.just this way.

```
- <categories>
- <category>
  <id>0</id> 
  <name>Music</name> 
  </category>
- <category>
  <id>1</id> 
  <name>Sport</name> 
  </category>
- <category>
  <id>2</id> 
  <name>News</name> 
  </category>
  </categories>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `XDocument` class from the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace:

```
XDocument myXml = new XDocument(new XElement("categories",
                                   new XElement("category",
                                      new XElement("id", "0"),
                                      new XElement("name", "music")),
                                   new XElement("category",
                                      new XElement("id", "1"),
                                      new XElement("name", "Sport")),
                                   new XElement("category",
                                      new XElement("id", "2"),
                                      new XElement("name", "News"))));
string xmlString = myXml.ToString();
// Or you could save it to a file, a stream, etc:
myXml.Save("Categories.xml");
```

This outputs:

```
<categories>
    <category>
        <id>0</id>
        <name>music</name>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Sport</name>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>News</name>
    </category> 
</categories>
```

[XDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var str = @"<categories>
    <category>
      <id>0</id>
      <name>Music</name>
    </category>
    <category>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Sport</name>
    </category>
    <category>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>News</name>
    </category>
  </categories>";
            Response.Write(str);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: +1 for the simple and obvious answer :)

Comment: However, I missed the point. OP needs a file, not a string written on a Stream.

Comment: It'd be quite simple to use a StreamReader to write your string out to a file.  The OP's question wasn't all that clear (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

You could try serializing a class to XML, there is a good tutorial for that here:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization